# linkedin api v2: "Not enough permissions to access" for /liveAssetActions

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to use the Live Video API in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/live-video/?context=linkedin/consumer/context

It says here r_member_live, w_member_live and r_liteprofile permissions are required. I have added Share on LinkedIn, Sign In with LinkedIn and Marketing Developer Platform products in the developer portal and no other products appear. However, I was only able to get r_liteprofile from the required permissions for the Live Video API.

When I request the https://api.linkedin.com/v2/liveAssetActions?action=register API link, I get the error "Not enough permissions to access: POST-register /liveAssetActions".